# Linked list segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I have problem with linked lists. I have two structures:

```
struct ekstra
{
    char isim[256];
    int deger;
    struct ekstra *sonra;
};

struct node
{
    char name[256];
    int val;
    struct ekstra *next;    
};
```

and I have these:

```
struct ekstra *tmp;
struct node dizi[12];
```

Somewhere in my code there is

```
tmp = dizi[k].next;
tmp=tmp->sonra;
```

and if I do this:

```
tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct ekstra));
```

there is no problem.

But if I do this:

```
dizi[k].next->sonra = malloc(sizeof(struct ekstra));
```

I get a SegFault. Why is this happening?

Comment: You're best off running the code with the help of a debugger. On linux, valgrind is great for pointing out segmentation faults. Also, on Windows, the visual studio debugger is quite useful.

Comment: Maybe you misuse array index `k`. Please post full code

Comment: @GeorgeGaál Please don't ask for the full code, but more complete code that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Drise That is to say "the least amount of complete code that can reproduce the problem." I agree with George that you need to ensure that k is within the bounds of the array and also ensure that next is not null? The GNU Debugger would also be useful for troubleshooting this.

Comment: k is 0 here there is no problem with k

Comment: code is http://codepad.org/DP4o3ZMD

Comment: file is http://codepad.org/GMvBWE7W

Comment: @RobKielty I can agree with that. However, We don't want the *full* code here, just what's relevant. Some may see *full* and post their entire project.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking strangers to spot errors in your code by inspection is not productive.  You should identify (or at least isolate) the problem by using a debugger or print statements, and then come back with a more specific question (once you've narrowed it down to a 10-line [test-case](http://sscce.org)).

Comment: @Drise We're in total agreement :) but I just wanted to emphasise the word "least" as you had suggested "*more* complete code" I thought "more" is more than less and if "more" was confused with "full" then we could end up with more code but what we want is just enough code which should be *less* code. D'ya get me? lol I did absolutely understand what you meant though. It was just a clarifying point.

Comment: @RobKielty You are completely right. I suppose I said *more* as in "more code than you *have* right now", not "more code than we *need*". I think my southern phrasing is slipping into my typing 0_0.

Comment: dokuman.txt using name 13 type. Perhaps, "Mestree" is typo "Mestre".

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
dizi[k].next->sonra = malloc(sizeof(struct ekstra));
```

is dereferencing

```
dizi[k].next
```

and I suspect that has a junk value.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines:

```
tmp = dizi[k].next;
tmp = tmp->sonra;
```

probably copy an invalid pointer into `tmp`.  When you assign to `tmp` with `malloc()`, the valid pointer from `malloc()` overwrites the invalid value already in `tmp`.

When you use:

```
dizi[k].next->sonra = malloc(sizeof(struct ekstra));
```

you are referencing the invalid pointer (to evaluate the address where the `sonra` member is stored), and that is causing the segmentation fault.

If you wrote:

```
*tmp = 0;
```

you would probably get a segmentation fault too.